# Creating IEnumerable of T in method header

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am trying to do this:

```
public static BatchInfo CreateBatch(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> rows)
{
```

Or:

```
public static BatchInfo CreateBatch(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<var>> rows)
{
```

Both of which give errors.  Previously, I had this:

```
public static BatchInfo CreateBatch(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> rows)
{
```

It was fine; except, now, I need to change `rows` from `<string>` to `<var>` since I will have strings, dates, ints, etc.  Initially, I thought I was only going to have strings...

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I think you need to read on what is `var`..

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Basically, I need to change IEnumerable<string> to a variable type.  I won't have just strings; but, I will have dates, ints, etc.

Comment: Yes I know what you need, but take a look at how to use `var`. It's really not what you think it is.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I see, "var isn't a type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static BatchInfo CreateBatch(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> rows)
{
```

Comment: @user1477388 you may need to check the type so you can handle it appropriately, but yes, it should work.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static BatchInfo CreateBatch<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> rows)
{
```

I think you had the right idea with `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, but you need to make the method declaration generic as well.

Answer (score 1):

`var` isn't a type. It's a keyword that is used for `implicit typing`, and it's only used to reduce redundancy when declaring variables. Since it's not a type it means you can't use it as your generic parameter.

I guess what you're looking for is either `object` or `dynamic` (.NET 4+ only)

```
public static BatchInfo CreateBatch(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> rows)
public static BatchInfo CreateBatch(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<dynamic>> rows)
```

Both of these might do what you want but are ugly and will probably cause lots of issues for you. I'd suggest probably creating different methods for each type, but I'm not fully sure what you're trying to do.

A generic method parameter might also work

```
public static BatchInfo CreateBatch<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> rows)
```